# Неявное воздействие scanf на другие переменные во Flat Assembler

Tags: c, ассемблер, fasm

```
    format ELF

section '.data' writeable
    a db 0
    b db 0
    c db 0
    d db 0
    res dq 0
    helloString db "Задача №443\n",0
    rawStr db "%s",0
    rawInt db "%d",0
    inputFormat db "Введите %s: ",0
    outputFormat dd "%f",0
    a_lit db "A",0
    b_lit db "B",0
    c_lit db "C",0
    d_lit db "D",0
    two db 2
    twopointfive dq 2.5


section '.text' executable
public main
extrn scanf
extrn printf
print_this:
fst qword[res]

    push dword[res+4]
    push dword[res]
    push outputFormat
    call printf
    add esp, 12
ret

triangle: ;Вычисление площади треугольника, перед этим нужно поместить в стек его стороны
    fldz            ;Кладём ноль на вершину стека Стек: 0|A|B|C
    fadd st0,st1    ;Прибавляем к нему A                A|A|B|C
    fadd st0,st2    ;                  B              A+B|A|B|C
    fadd st0,st3    ;                  C            A+B+C|A|B|C
    fild dword [two];Кладём двойку                2|A+B+C|A|B|C
    fdivp           ;Делим на неё                       p|A|B|C
    fsub st1,st0    ;Вычитаем                         p|p-A|B|C
    fsub st2,st0    ;                               p|p-A|p-B|C
    fsub st3,st0    ;                             p|p-A|p-B|p-C
    fmulp           ;Умножаем                   p*(p-A)|p-B|p-C
    fmulp           ;                         p*(p-A)*(p-B)|p-C
    fmulp           ;                       p*(p-A)*(p-B)*(p-C)
    fsqrt           ;Извлекаем корень                         S
ret
main:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    finit
    push helloString ;Приветствие
    push rawStr
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    push a_lit
    push inputFormat
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    push a
    push rawInt
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    push b_lit
    push inputFormat
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    push b
    push rawInt
    call scanf
    add esp,8

    push c_lit
    push inputFormat
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    push c
    push rawInt
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    push d_lit
    push inputFormat
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    push d
    push rawInt
    call scanf
    add esp,8

    fld1
    fild dword[two]
    fild dword[a]
    call triangle

    fild dword [two]
    fld qword [twopointfive]
    fild dword [b]
    call triangle

    fild dword [c]
    fild dword [d]
    fld qword [twopointfive]
    call triangle

    faddp
    faddp

    fstp qword[res]

    push dword[res+4]
    push dword[res]
    push outputFormat
    call printf
    add esp, 12

    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Все расчёты происходят правильно, но результат оказывается офигенно большим числом, по той причине, что на переменные a,b,c,d что-то воздействует. Если После считывания переменной а занести её в регистр st0 и вызвать функцию print_this, то всё будет нормально и число будет соответствовать действительности, однако если сделать то же самое после того, как считается значение b, то значение а будет совсем другим, а именно 513.0, если изначально оно было равно единице. С каждым последующим считыванием оно будет всё больше расти и вырастет до нескольких миллионов, но всегда остаётся целым. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: переменные объявлены как `db`, (`char` в терминах С), а читать ты из пытаешься как `int`, вот он и портит соседние данные... Или измени формат на "%hhd" или объяви данные как `int` (`dd` в терминах FASM ЕМНИП).

Comment: @Fat-Zer В таком случае результат выполнения программы получается `-nan`

Comment: в каком именно «таком»? да, других ошибок это не исключает...

Comment: @PaulShishmarev, сначала исправьте `db` на `dd`, как уже сказали выше, дальше запускайте под отладчиком и смотрите, в какой момент получается nan.